# Apply a predicate to a list of getters in Java

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, predicate

I want to test if ALL getters of an bean have text.

The straight-forward way is a test like this:

```
boolean result=
     StringUtils.hasText(bean.getProperty1()) && 
     StringUtils.hasText(bean.getProperty2()) &&
     .....
```

But I'm wondering if there's a must succinct way in Java 8 such that I don't have to repeat the predicate function:

```
   Utility.appplyPredicate(StringUtils:hasText,
          bean.getProperty1(), bean.getProperty2(),...)
```

Or even better using method references:

```
   Utility.appplyPredicate(StringUtils:hasText, bean
          Bean:getProperty1, Bean:getProperty2,...
```

I suppose I could write something like this using a varargs, but perhaps there's a way to do it with the JRE or an existing library like Apache or Spring?

Comment: A straightforward way would be using [bean validation](https://beanvalidation.org/)

Answer (score 4):

That's rather easy to do with streams:

```
Stream.of(bean.getProperty1(), bean.getProperty2(), …)
      .allMatch(StringUtils::hasText);
```